# How can we make one column twice the width of another, without using absolute values?

Tags: html, css, dom

Example:

```
<table width="500">
    <tr>
        <td width="50">1</td>
        <td width="100%">2</td>
        <td width="100">3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If I'm not mistaken, if a width is given as a percentage, it's a percent of the *total* width of the parent element, not a percent of the *remaining* width, correct?

Okay, fine, so what happens when we mix percentages and pixel widths? In the example above, column 2 [takes up as much space as it can](http://jsfiddle.net/CYnex/3/), and squishes 1 and 2 against the sides *but* it does not hide them; it allows them enough room to display their contents, even if `overflow:hidden` is set.

If instead we [change column 2 to 10%](http://jsfiddle.net/CYnex/2/), again the percentage seems to take priority, however it still seems to respect the proportionality of 1 and 3 -- 3 is still twice as wide as 1, even if the exact widths aren't as specified.

So what if we want to set 2 of the columns, and let the 3rd column fill the remaining space? Easy! Just completely [omit the value](http://jsfiddle.net/CYnex/4/).

Fine, but what if we want to set one column to an explicit pixel width, and have the 2nd be twice the width of the 3rd to fill the remaining space? Is that even possible in HTML/CSS?

[sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYnex/1/)

Comment: Btw according to the HTML5 spec, the width attribute on TD elements is obsolete and *["must not be used by authors"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features)*.

Comment: @Sime: That's not the point. I could have just as easily set them with CSS, and they'd behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in Chrome, but not IE or Edge:

```
<table style="width: 500px;">
    <tr style="display: flex;">
        <td style="width: 50px;">1</td>
        <td style="flex-grow: 2;">2</td>
        <td style="flex-grow: 1;">3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, with `<div>` it appears to work in Chrome and Edge:

```
<div style="width: 500px; display: flex;">
    <div style="width: 50px;">1</div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 2;">2</div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1;">3</div>
</div>
```

I haven't used flex much, but I believe the number after `flex-grow` is the amount of remaining space to be taken up by each element in a flex element.

**Edit:** Flexbox layout is currently in W3C Candidate Recommendation. You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/).